# How to set results retried from sqlite db table to array in react native?

Tags: sqlite, react-native

Here is my code

```
var employeeList = [] ;
let db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', createFromLocation : "~example.db", location: 'Library'}, false,false);

db.transaction((tx) => {     
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employees', [], (tx, results) => {      
      console.log("Query completed");
      var len = results.rows.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let row = results.rows.item(i); 
        employeeList.push(row.name);        
      }
      this.setState({employees:employeeList});   
        db.closeDatabase();       
    });
});
alert(this.state.employees);
```

I am able to set result to employeeList inside a transaction.But When I am checking employeeList outside the transaction,it is getting blank...
What I have to do to set results.row to employees object..

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous. You're asking for a value before the DB transaction has been performed. You need to use promises or callbacks to know when the query has executed.

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriel mentioned, you need to wrap the call in a Promise. I provided an example of how you might want to do it.

```
    const getEmployees = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var employeeList = [] ;
    let db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', createFromLocation : "~example.db", location: 'Library'}, false,false);

    db.transaction((tx) => {     
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employees', [], (tx, results) => {      
        console.log("Query completed");
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            let row = results.rows.item(i); 
            employeeList.push(row.name);        
        }
        db.closeDatabase();

        // resolve promise
        resolve(employeeList)
    });
});

getEmployees.then(data => {
    this.setState({
        employees:employeeList
    })
})
```